# Метод for...of JS Ecma6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Студентам нужно набрать 70 баллов, чтобы сдать экзамен. Данная программа объявляет массив с результатами. Напишите код для подсчета и вывода в консоль количества студентов, успешно сдавших экзамен.

```
let scores = [68,95,54,84,77,75,63,74,69,80,71,63]

let passedExam =[];// объявляем массив для сдавших студентов

for (let value of scores){
for (value > 70) { //определяем студентов, набравший проходной балл 
    passedExam.push; //добавляем сдавших студентов к новому массиву
}
console.log(passedExam.length);// Определяем число сдавших путем вычисления длины массива
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А вы смотрели как работает метод `push` и что на вход требует? Кстати, у вас даже он не как метод, а как свойство написан

Comment: А ещё вместо `for (value > 70)` должно быть `if (value > 70)`

Comment: Поменял for на if, как вы и сказали. Сейчас буду перечитывать про метод push. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь несколько ошибок:

1. опечатка в определении условия (for вместо if)
2. сама проверка должна быть >=
3. метод push нужно вызывать, и вызывать с аргументом
4. консоль лог нужно вынести из цикла

```
let scores = [68, 95, 54, 84, 77, 75, 63, 74, 69, 80, 71, 63]

let passedExam = [];// объявляем массив для сдавших студентов

for (let value of scores) {
  if (value >= 70) { //определяем студентов, набравший проходной балл 
    passedExam.push(value); //добавляем сдавших студентов к новому массиву
  }
}
console.log(passedExam.length);// Определяем число сдавших путем вычисления длины массива
```

Ну и конечно лучше оформить код как функцию. Да и к алгоритму есть вопросы (например зачем нужен массив "passedExam", можно просто пополнять счетчик):

```
const commonScores = [68, 95, 54, 84, 77, 75, 63, 74, 69, 80, 71, 63];

const countPassedExam = (scores) => {
  let result = 0;

  for (let value of scores) {
    if (value >= 70) {
      result += 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(countPassedExam(commonScores));
```

Ну и последний этап, JS это высокоуровневый язык, такие ориентированы на удобство чтения кода, циклы это низкоуровневый инструмент, для лучшей "понятности" лучше пользоваться функциями высшего порядка:

```
const commonScores = [68, 95, 54, 84, 77, 75, 63, 74, 69, 80, 71, 63];

const countPassedExam = (scores) => scores.filter((s) => s >= 70).length;

console.log(countPassedExam(commonScores));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за то, что уделили столько времени на подробное разъяснение. Ваш комментарий действительно очень полезен. Постараюсь запомнить и не допускать подобных ошибок в будущем.

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать `for of` не обязательно, то можно и покомпактнее:

```
const passedExam = scores.filter(el => el > 70);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно переписать следующим образом

```
let scores = [68,95,54,84,77,75,63,74,69,80,71,63]

let passedExam =[];// объявляем массив для сдавших студентов

for (let value of scores){
    if(value > 70) { //определяем студентов, набравший проходной балл 
        passedExam.push(value); //добавляем сдавших студентов к новому массиву
    }
}

console.log(passedExam.length);// Определяем число сдавших путем вычисления длины массива
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Теперь все заработало. Получается я просто не передал информацию методу push и использовал не тот логический оператор.